# How WS Federation Authentication Module validates token

Tags: .net, wif, adfs

I'm trying to understand WIF and AD FS. I found a lot of useful information, but can't find any details on how WS FAM is validating token received from STS.

I found [this sequence diagram](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ff359114.1a314389-f570-418a-a34e-31ce00e0bdc6%28l=en-us%29.png) which explains the process, but there in step 6 there is only annotation that token validation is handled by FAM. I found [some resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517293.aspx) on this too, but it doesn't seem to be  too relevant.

What I'd like to know is if WIF is validating the token offline (based on some rules created when the trust with issuer was established or something) or online (by asking issuer itself). Should I even care?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue you shouldn't care :-), but we are curious, aren't we? And there's value in knowing how things actually work.

The validation happens on the app with no contact with the STS (e.g. ADFS), that's because in general, the token is digitally signed (and optionally encrypted) and WIF has all the information and means to check the integrity of it.

A great source of WIF internals can be found in Vittorio's book:
[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows%C2%AE-Identity-Foundation-Dev/dp/0735627185](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627185)

There's a lot of information on how all the modules interact and work.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I was curious :).